# "List index out of range" error when iterated with for loop

Tags: python, list

I am beginner. I am writing a python program that removes '!' and '.' from the list. User enters any string. Python converts it into a list and removes ! and . and again prints the altered list. Here is my code :

```
x = input("Enter a string: ")

y = list(x)

for i in range(len(y) - 1):

    if y[i] == '!' or y[i] == '.':
        y.pop(i)
print("Altered list is: ",y)
```

Even when I do `range(len(y)-1)` to `range(len(y))` it shows the error:
`List index out of range`.

Comment: remove item while iterating: no good

Comment: You're modifying the list on each iteration by deleting items from it. Don't do that. Instead, rebuild your list that contains the items you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the list that you are modifying... It cannot end well.

Try this approach instead:

```
y = [elt for elt in y if elt != "!" or elt != "."]
```

It will rebuild your list, omitting the undesired elements.